# How GROUP BY and OVER WINDOW differ in FlinkSQL?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

One can use windows in Flink in two different manners

```
SELECT key, MAX(value)
  FROM table
 GROUP BY key, TUMBLE(ts, INTERVAL '5' MINUTE)
```

and

```
SELECT key, MAX(value) OVER w
  FROM table
 WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY key ORDER BY ts ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

I wonder if those two mechanisms can express the same thing or what's the main difference and possible use cases for both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both queries compute different results that correspond to the semantics of regular SQL. So the difference is not Flink specific but defined by the SQL Standard.

---

The first query

```
SELECT key, MAX(value)
  FROM table
 GROUP BY key, TUMBLE(ts, INTERVAL '5' MINUTE)
```

groups records per `key` and 5 minute buckets. Every 5 minutes the query produces one row per `key` value with the maximum `value`. For each group, multiple rows are aggregated to a single row.

---

The second query

```
SELECT key, MAX(value) OVER w
  FROM table
 WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY key ORDER BY ts ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```

produces one row for every row of the input (`table`). A result row has the maximum `value` for the `key` value that was observed so far (rows are ordered by `ts`). Note that multiple rows are not aggregated to a single row; each input row results in one output row. Moreover, the range of the maximum aggregation can be more than 5 minutes. In fact it's the whole `key` partition in this example.

Comment: what if I used LAST_VALUE(value) instead of MAX? is it any different from SELECT key, value FROM table?

Comment: It's the same difference as with MAX(). The query with OVER / WINDOW will still produce one output row for each input row and the "aggregation-range" is also the full past of the key partition, not the key's 5-minute window.

Answer (score 0):

Fabian's answer is very correct. If still have any questions, you can refer to this example. The example comes from [Rolling Aggregations on Time Series Data](https://github.com/0x822a5b87/flink-sql-cookbook/blob/main/aggregations-and-analytics/04_over/04_over.md)

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temperature_measurements (
  measurement_time TIMESTAMP(3),
  city STRING,
  temperature FLOAT, 
  WATERMARK FOR measurement_time AS measurement_time - INTERVAL '15' SECONDS
)
WITH (
  'connector' = 'faker',
  'fields.measurement_time.expression' = '#{date.past ''15'',''SECONDS''}',
  'fields.temperature.expression' = '#{number.numberBetween ''0'',''50''}',
  'fields.city.expression' = '#{regexify ''(Chicago|Munich|Berlin|Portland|Hangzhou|Seatle|Beijing|New York){1}''}'
);
```

here is the over window usage:

```sql
SELECT 
  measurement_time,
  city, 
  temperature,
  AVG(CAST(temperature AS FLOAT)) OVER last_minute AS avg_temperature_minute,
  MAX(temperature) OVER last_minute AS min_temperature_minute,
  MIN(temperature) OVER last_minute AS max_temperature_minute,
  STDDEV(CAST(temperature AS FLOAT)) OVER last_minute AS stdev_temperature_minute
FROM temperature_measurements 
WINDOW last_minute AS (
  PARTITION BY city
  ORDER BY measurement_time
  RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '1' MINUTE PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW 
);
```

and the result goes to:

[image]

and here is the group by usage :

```sql
SELECT
    city,
    AVG(CAST(temperature AS FLOAT)) AS avg_temperature_minute,
        MAX(temperature) AS min_temperature_minute,
        MIN(temperature) AS max_temperature_minute,
        STDDEV(CAST(temperature AS FLOAT)) AS stdev_temperature_minute
FROM temperature_measurements 
group by 
city,
TUMBLE(measurement_time, INTERVAL '1' MINUTES);
```

and the result goes to :

[image]

so, here is the final difference:

1. we cannot select measurement_time, temperature because Expression 'measurement_time', 'temperature' is not being grouped；
2. for every row, the over window prouce an aggregated value. for every **row with group**, the group by produce an aggregated value.